# Notice in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#522

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just have installed MySQL **Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)** and phpMyAdmin **Version information: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2**
When I am accessing database through phpMyAdmin, it is showing warning message

> Notice in ./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php#522

Can anyone help please?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You just need to add one thing in file `./libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php`. Below is the code to add line no 522

**Before adding fixing code**

[image]

**After Adding fixing code**

[image]

I think this will help you to fix that error messages issue.

Comment: Probably located here (on ubuntu): `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php`

Answer (score 5):

open a **`DBIMysqli.class.php`** File.

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/DBIMysqli.class.php
```

And Then Go To Line Number : **522**

> before Replace Code This Line

```
  $fields[$k]->type =  $typeAr[$field->type];
```

> After Replace This Line

```
$fields[$k]->type = isset($typeAr[$field->type]) ? $typeAr[$field->type] : null;
```